# Nested IF, INDEX and MATCH in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, match

I'm trying to return a value in Google sheets. 
This is done using an Index Match as follows, which does work:

```
=iferror(index(Data!B:B, match(B5339,Data!G:G,0)),"Not Found")
```

I'd now like to expand this, so that if this first test fails, try looking up that same data in another sheet....

```
=iferror(if(index(Data!B:B, match(B5340,Data!G:G,0),if(index(HeadOfficeLeads!B:B, match(B5340,HeadOfficeLeads!A:A,0))))),"Not found")
```

This outputs the fail msg of "Not Found". 
However, although the first test is indeed false, the second test is true (this second data set does in fact hold a match).

NB - the data containing this correct match on the 2nd sheet is created by a `UNIQUE ( FILTER, FWIW....`

For some reason, it doesnt look like the second IF statement is being run - and the whole thing doesnt work, giving the error "Wrong number of arguments".

I have a feeling the argument issue is that the first test doesnt have an "if false" clause - but believe the "`IFERROR`" parent should handle this? 
If not, where would I put the "if false clause" for the `IF's`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any `if`, because `iferror` already contains an `if` statement in its logic (as its name suggests). Here is an example of nested `iferror` statements, simplified for clarity:

```
=iferror(match("a", A1:A5, 0), iferror(match("a", B1:B5", 0), "not found"))
```

This will return the position of "a" in column A, if it's there; otherwise, it will return its position in column B if it's there, otherwise it returns "not found".

Works the same with `index` or anything else around `match` function.